# App Angular avoid CORS(preflight) on Apache

Tags: angular, apache, cors

I have been facing a problem with CORS, on my local development I fixed the problem creating a local proxy on node.js, but now I need to deploy my App on Apache WebServer. 
How can I create proxy pass as node.js on Apache Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem,creating a ProxyPass in Apache Web Server like this:

```
# Proxy for BaseServer
<LocationMatch "/BPAManagement">
    #Header add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "http://xxxx:9608/BPAManagement"
</LocationMatch>
```

First you need to change all http requests to your Webserver(Apache) for example : REST Service to backend:http://xxxx:9608/BPAManagement to http://localhost/BPAManagement. Therefore all HTTP requests to your backend now will pass on localserver then ProxyPass redirect to your original backend. So now your borwser understands all HTTP requests are same origin
If you want to add HTTP Header take a look HttpIntercetModule : https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8